# Build makefile with source and header in separate folder

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm trying to build a Makefile with separate folder for my sources and my headers. I have a the root of my project that contain an include folder that holds my .hpp files, and a source folder that holds my .cpp files. How can i build the Makefile that it builds all the .cpp with the respective .hpp files ?

How to create the program output in a folder called build ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is so diverse, there's a LOT of ways to do this, but the end result is `-I<your hpp path>` (or -J) needs to be passed to the compiler to tell it additional include paths to search when resolving `#include`

The path needs to relative to the invocation of the rule directory, or relative to the file (I'm pretty sure the compiler searches both).

A lot of makefiles use CPPOPTS and CCOPTS or some variant of that in the makefile to pass extra options to the C or CPP compiler.   Try adding:

```
CPPOPTS += -I..\include
```

To your makefile (assuming you've segregated your source and include files that way).

Again, this is ALL dependent on your makefile.

Comment: Google gives 1590 hits for `CPPOPTS` and 360000 hits for `CPPFLAGS`. So, in relative terms, not a lot of makefiles use `CPPOPTS`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to build a Makefile with separate folder for my sources and my headers.

An alternative way would be to have your headers in the same directory as your `.cpp` files. And in that top level include folder you can put symbolic links to the headers.

Comment: I think this solution would suffer from being unable to added to most revision control systems due to the symbolic links, so I wouldn't recommend it.  A very hackish thing I've done, however, is add a local .h file that only includes the real one that wasn't local using the known relative path.   I only did this in rare cases that had to do with avoiding disturbing already existing makefiles but needing to share source/headers between two projects.  Again, I don't recommend that.  Use `-I` or `-J`